# Compare value in a dataframe to multiple columns of another dataframe to get a list of lists where entries match in an efficient way

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes and i want to find all entries of the second dataframe where a specific value occurs.

As an example:

```
df1:
   NID
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5

df2:
   EID  N1  N2  N3  N4
0    1   1   2  13  12
1    2   2   3  14  13
2    3   3   4  15  14
3    4   4   5  16  15
4    5   5   6  17  16
5    6   6   7  18  17
6    7   7   8  19  18
7    8   8   9  20  19
8    9   9  10  21  20
9   10  10  11  22  21
```

Now, what i basically want, is a list of lists with the values EID (from df2) where the values NID (from df1) occur in any of the columns N1,N2,N3,N4:

Solution would be:

```
sol = [[1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

The desired solution explained:

The solution has 5 entries (len(sol = 5)) since I have 5 entries in df1.
The first entry in sol is 1 because the value NID = 1 only appears in the columns N1,N2,N3,N4 for EID=1 in df2.
The second entry in sol refers to the value NID=2 (of df1) and has the length 2 because NID=2 can be found in column N1 (for EID=2) and in column N2 (for EID=1). Therefore, the second entry in the solution is [1,2] and so on.

What I tried so far is looping for each element in df1 and then looping for each element in df2 to see if NID is in any of the columns N1,N2,N3,N4. This solution works but for huge dataframes (each df can have up to some thousand entries) this solution becomes extremely time-consuming.
Therefore I was looking for a much more efficient solution.

My code as implemented:

Input data:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'NID':[1,2,3,4,5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'EID':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                  'N1':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                  'N2':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],
                  'N3':[13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22],
                  'N4':[12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]})
```

solution acquired using looping:

```
sol= []

for idx,node in df1.iterrows():
    x = []
    for idx2,elem in df2.iterrows():
        if node['NID'] == elem['N1']:
            x.append(elem['EID'])
        if node['NID'] == elem['N2']:
            x.append(elem['EID'])
        if node['NID'] == elem['N3']:
            x.append(elem['EID'])
        if node['NID'] == elem['N4']:
            x.append(elem['EID'])
    sol.append(x)

print(sol)
```

If anyone has a solution where I do not have to loop, I would be very happy. Maybe using a numpy function or something like cKDTrees but unfortunately I have no idea on how to get this problem solved in a faster way.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reshape with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt), filter with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) as list. Then [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) and convert [`tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
out = (df2
    .melt('EID')   # reshape to long form
    # filter the values that are in df1['NID']
    .loc[lambda d: d['value'].isin(df1['NID'])]
    # aggregate as list
    .groupby('value')['EID'].agg(list)
    # ensure all original NID are present in order
    # and convert to list
    .reindex(df1['NID']).tolist()
)
```

Alternative with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df3 = df2.set_index('EID')

out = (df3
    .where(df3.isin(df1['NID'].tolist())).stack()
    .reset_index(name='group')
    .groupby('group')['EID'].agg(list)
    .reindex(df1['NID']).tolist()
)
```

Output:

```
[[1], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3], [5, 4]]
```

Comment: Do you want I remove my answer?

Comment: @Corralien I think you posted during my edit, up to you, not necessarily ;)